# Find users total hours streamed

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, pivot

This table is a "heartbeat" tracking event where one row is generated each minute for each streamer while that streamer is live. If a streamer is live for 60 minutes, 60 rows would be generated in this table

```
Create Table minute_streamed
(
     time_minute datetime ,
     username varchar(50) ,
     category varchar(50) ,
     concurrent_viewers int
);
    
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-03-18 12:00:00', 'alex','Fornite',125) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-03-18 12:01:00', 'alex','Fornite',130) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-03-19 15:30:00', 'jamie','Just Chatting',13) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-03-19 15:31:00', 'jamie','Food & Drink',15) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-03-20 10:30:00', 'rick','Call of Duty: Black Ops',150) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-03-20 10:31:00', 'rick','Call of Duty: Modern Warfare',120) ;
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-21 09:30:00', 'rick','Fornite',120) ;
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-20 10:31:00', 'rick','Call of Duty: Modern Warfare',120) ;
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-21 09:30:00', 'rick','Fornite',120) ;
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-20 10:31:00', 'jamie','Call of Duty: Modern Warfare',120) ;
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-21 09:30:00', 'jamie','Fornite',120) ;
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-18 12:00:00', 'alex','Fornite',125) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-04-18 12:01:00', 'alex','Fornite',130) ; 
Insert into minute_streamed values ('2020-06-18 14:00:00', 'alex','Fornite',120) ;
```

Alex has two entries in March. That means he streamed for 2 minutes. So, his hourly streamed for March will be 2/60. 2 minutes / 1 hour (60 minutes)

I am trying to write a query that returns a row for each streamer with columns for their total hours streamed (in any category) and percentage of hourly streamed in call of duty game category.

Can you help me modify my query?

```
select 
    username 
    ,case 
        when if_call_of_duty = 1 then sum(hour_streamed)
    end as call_of_hour 
from(
select 
      username 
     ,category
     ,count(*)/60 as hour_streamed
     ,CASE
        when category like 'Call of Duty%' THEN 1
        else  0
      end as if_call_of_duty 
from minute_streamed
group by username,category) as temp 
group by username,if_call_of_duty
```

I am trying to get an output like this:

```
username total_hours_streamed percantege_call_of_duty
alex            10                      0
rick            10                      0.50
```

total hours stream for each user, and percentage of streaming hours for call of duty game category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results do not seem consistent with your data. Based on your explanation and existing query, I suspect that you are looking for conditional aggregation. In MySQL, you would phrase this as:

```
select 
    username,
    count(*)/60 as hour_streamed,
    avg(category like 'Call of Duty%') as if_call_of_duty 
from minute_streamed
group by username
```

This aggregates records by `username`; `hour_streamed` is the total number of record per user (in all categories), divided by `60`. `if_call_of_duty` is the *ratio* of records that relate to categories that start with `'Call of Duty'`.

Comment: if_call_of_duty column shoul have the hourly % of category starts with 'call of duty'. For example, jamie streamed 0.0667 hours in total. What % of 0.0667 hours coming from call of duty category. Hope that explains

Comment: @Eren: that’s what the query does. It gives a *ratio* (a value between 0 and 1) - you can multiply it by 100 if you want a percentage.

Comment: can you also help me with "For each calendar month, output the list of streamers who increased their hours streamed from the previous calendar month" ?